# An error occurred while sending to the queue: Unrecognized error -1072824273 (0xc00e002f).Ensure that MSMQ is installed and running

Tags: windows, msmq, msmq-wcf

Hi got the message below when sending an message to a remote queue.

`An error occurred while sending to the queue: Unrecognized error -1072824273 (0xc00e002f).Ensure that MSMQ is installed and running. If you are sending to a local queue, ensure the queue exists with the required access mode and authorization`.

Another test show that with other account i could send the message to the remote server without any problem.

Comment: That is MQ_ERROR_NO_INTERNAL_USER_CERT, "No internal certificate is registered, or the registered certificate is corrupted".  Well, not big news.  Why the machine requires a certificate or why it isn't configured correctly is drastically unclear and does not have anything to do with programming.  Best to leave this up to IT staff, they can ask about it at serverfault.com

Comment: Indeed, it has nothing to have with code. I find out the answer and post below.

Comment: It were 2 problems. The "Signure is invalid Message" was fired by other application and had nothing to do with is. I removed the reference to this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After dig through many posts find myself the solution.
It simple needs to register the client certificate for the pair client machine and account. I have no idea why one account has the certificate and the other don't. To register the certificate it needs to do this(no need to create a certificate):

1. Run mmc with the account at the client machine
2. Select Message Queuing item from the tree view[image]
3. Select properties form the context menu (Right click button)
4. Select the "User Certificate tab" and click Register. Select the pair for the client machine and current account (production account).[image]
5. Try again.

Comment: Found out after that  some accounts had registed many certificates for different pairs machine and accounts. It looks the register is automatic, but for some reason it failed for this pair. Something is missing.

Answer (score 0):

If you have too many registrations, you can clean up.

[Clearing up MSMQ certificates from Active Directory](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/johnbreakwell/2008/09/15/clearing-up-msmq-certificates-from-active-directory/)

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution was provided by Microsoft support:

> Often this issue happens due to insufficient privileges or a network
>   disruption when the queues were first made. So another solution is to
>   delete them and recrate them completely with an account with
>   sufficient privileges.
>
> If they are performing well now with no lost messages, I would not
>   recommend that we do this, but that we continue to monitor the
>   situation.